# I need help aligning the nav bar with the header on my website

Tags: html, css

I need help aligning the nav bar with the header on my website, as done on the "why" page. [Here is the website.](https://ariabrauchli.github.io/Universal-Design/why.html)I am trying to get it to look the same on the home, What, How, and FAQ pages as well.
Here is the "Why" Code, my CSS, and the "what" page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Universal Design Hub</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="projstyles.css"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <header role="banner">
        <h1>Welcome to the Universal Design Hub</h1>
        <h2>Empowering designers to create for everyone</h2>
        <details>
            <summary>
                Page Navigation
            </summary>
            
            <p>
                <nav class="nav1">
                    <ul class="navvy">
                        <li><a href="#why"><span aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons">question_mark</span> Why?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </details>
    </header>

    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="project.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="why.html">Why?</a></li>
            <li><a href="what.html">What?</a></li>
            <li><a href="how.html">How?</a></li>
            <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ and Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="why" role="region" aria-labelledby="why-heading">
        <h2 id="why-heading">Why Universal Design?</h2>
        <p>
            Universal design is not just a concept; it is a fundamental shift in the way we approach
            web development and design. It goes beyond aesthetics and functionality; it's about inclusivity
            and ensuring that everyone, regardless of abilities, can access and interact with digital content.
        </p>

        <ol class="whyd">
            <li>
                <strong>Accessibility for All:</strong> Universal design ensures that websites are
                accessible to everyone, including individuals with disabilities. By creating inclusive designs,
                we break down barriers and make the web a space where information is truly available for all.
            </li>

            <li>
                <strong>Future-Proofing:</strong> Designing with universal principles in mind is a proactive
                approach. It anticipates future needs and advancements in technology, ensuring that your
                creations remain relevant and usable as technology evolves.
            </li>

            <li>
                <strong>Social Responsibility:</strong> As designers, we have a responsibility to contribute
                positively to society. Embracing universal design is a step toward a more socially responsible
                and inclusive digital landscape.
            </li>

            <li>
                <strong>Better User Experience:</strong> Universal design improves the overall user experience
                for everyone. By considering diverse needs from the outset, we create interfaces that are more
                intuitive, user-friendly, and enjoyable for all users.
            </li>

            <li>
                <strong>Legal and Ethical Compliance:</strong> Many countries have laws and regulations
                that require websites to be accessible. Beyond legal compliance, embracing universal design is
                an ethical choice that aligns with creating a fair and equitable online environment.
            </li>
        </ol>

        <p>
            Join us in the movement towards a web that respects and includes every user. Let's champion
            universal design and make the internet a space where everyone can thrive.
        </p>
        <img src="https://www.nec.com/en/global/design/ud/images/ud_03.jpg" alt="An accessible world" style="width: 50%; max-width: 600px;">
    </section>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        <p>&copy; Designed by Aria Brauchli.</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=GFS+Didot&family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em 0;
    background-color: #FFF6EF;
}
h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}
h1{
    font-size: 30px;
}
header {
    font-family: 'Didot', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2E0D5;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2C4B3;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #F0F2F0;
}

section {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

footer {
    font-family: 'Didot', sans-serif;
    background-color: #DFF2ED;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        margin: 0; 
    }
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    nav a {
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .what{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        

    }
    img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
}
.home {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .why{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0;
   
  }
  .what{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0;
    
    
  }
  .how{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0;
  }
  .center {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
    
  }
  .center1 {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
    
  }
  .center3 {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;

    
  }
  .center2 {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
    
  }
 .navvy{
    background-color: #F2E0D5;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
 }

 .wtf{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;

 }

 a:hover{
    color:#000000;
 }
 a{
    color:#05242a;
 }

 ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-align: center;
  }
 .whyd{
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
    
 }
summary{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

What

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Universal Design Hub</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="projstyles.css"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <header role="banner">
        <h1>Welcome to the Universal Design Hub</h1>
        <h2>Empowering designers to create for everyone</h2>
        <details>
            <summary>
                Page Navigation
            </summary>
            
            <p>
                <nav class="nav1">
                    <ul class="navvy">
                    
                        <li><a href="#what"><span aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons">question_mark</span> What is Universal Design?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#7Principles"><span aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons">star</span> Seven Principles of Universal Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Benefits"><span aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons">thumb_up</span> Benefits of Universal Design</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
            </details>
    

    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="project.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="why.html">Why?</a></li>
            <li><a href="what.html">What?</a></li>
            <li><a href="how.html">How?</a></li>
            <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ and Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

    <section class="what" role="region" aria-labelledby="what-heading">
        <h2 id="what-heading">What is Universal Design?</h2>
        <p class="wtf">
            Universal design is an approach to creating products, environments, and systems that are
            usable by all people, to the greatest extent possible, without the need for adaptation
            or specialized design. In the context of web design, it means crafting websites and
            applications that can be accessed and used by individuals with diverse abilities and needs.
        </p>

        <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5c2cd3c49f8770b74f22e01a/591c0d7d-2982-4875-b342-9cfa78c71bb5/UD+post+%287%29.png" alt="Seven Principles of Universal Design" style="width: 50%; max-width: 600px;">

        <h3 id="7Principles">Seven Principles of Universal Design:</h3> 
        <ol class="center">
            <li><strong>Equitable Use:</strong> The design is useful and marketable to people with diverse abilities.</li>
            <li><strong>Flexibility in Use:</strong> The design accommodates a wide range of individual preferences and abilities.</li>
            <li><strong>Simple and Intuitive Use:</strong> Use of the design is easy to understand, regardless of the user's experience, knowledge, language skills, or current concentration level.</li>
            <li><strong>Perceptible Information:</strong> The design communicates necessary information effectively to the user, regardless of ambient conditions or the user's sensory abilities.</li>
            <li><strong>Tolerance for Error:</strong> The design minimizes hazards and the adverse consequences of accidental or unintended actions.</li>
            <li><strong>Low Physical Effort:</strong> The design can be used efficiently and comfortably with a minimum of fatigue.</li>
            <li><strong>Size and Space for Approach and Use:</strong> Appropriate size and space are provided for approach, reach, manipulation, and use, regardless of the user's body size, posture, or mobility.</li>
        </ol>

        <h3 id="Benefits">Benefits of Universal Design:</h3>
        <p>
            Embracing universal design in web development offers numerous benefits, including:
        </p>
        <ul class="center2">
            <li>Increased accessibility for people with disabilities.</li>
            <li>Improved user experience for all visitors.</li>
            <li>Future-proofing against technological advancements.</li>
            <li>Compliance with legal requirements and standards.</li>
            <li>Social responsibility and inclusivity.</li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            As web designers and developers, incorporating universal design principles leads to
            more inclusive, accessible, and user-friendly digital experiences for everyone.
        </p>
    </section>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        <p>&copy; Designed by Aria Brauchli.</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried altering the margin and the padding to no avail

Comment: In the first shown document, you have `<nav role="navigation">` _after_ the `header` element - in the second one, you have `<nav role="navigation">` _nested inside_ the `header` element.

Comment: Perhaps you can upload with display on the aplication. So we can know and we can help you

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked your code a bit see if this works:

```scss
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=GFS+Didot&family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .2em 0;
    background-color: #FFF6EF;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

header {
    font-family: 'Didot', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2E0D5;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: #F2C4B3;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0; /* Optional: Adjust the padding if needed */
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #F0F2F0;
}

section {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

footer {
    font-family: 'Didot', sans-serif;
    background-color: #DFF2ED;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    nav a {
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .what {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.home {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.why {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.what {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.how {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.center {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.center1 {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.center3 {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.center2 {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

.navvy {
    background-color: #F2E0D5;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.wtf {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

a {
    color: #05242a;
}

ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-align: center;
}

ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-align: center;
}

.whyd {
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: .2em 0;
}

summary {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

What i did was adding:

1. `position: relative;` on the `header` to use absolute positioning for the `nav` element relative to the `header`.
2. `position: absolute;` on the `nav` and `top: 100%;` will move the `nav` just below the `header`.
3. `width: 100%;` makes the navbar span the full width of the parent container (in this case, the `header`).
4. `display: block;` on `nav a` ensures each navigation link takes up the full width of its container.